# How do I prove inconsistency in FOL?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So I have to prove that this set S is inconsistent:

S = {{P(x),P(f(a)), ¬Q(z)}, {P(g(x’,x)),Q(x)},{¬P(y)}}

I just have no idea where to start. The only time I learned about inconsistency is when I learned about Skolem form, but I got no idea how to prove it. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The notion of inconsistent (at least a priori) only makes sense for a given proof system. What proof system are you using?

Comment: This is what I learned. Let F be a formula and S be a set of clauses in skolem normal form that represents the formula F. Then F is inconsistent if and only if S is inconsistent.

Comment: That might be true, but that doesn't help us if you don't specify what "inconsistent" means.

Comment: This is the only other thing I was given " we can find an interpretation I, such that I ⊨ S and I ⊭ F or reverse".

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of statements is inconsistent if and only if it has no model, i.e. it is impossible for all statements to be true at the same time.

This is equivalent to saying that the conjunction of all those sentences is a contradiction.

It is also equivalent to saying that the contradiction is a logical consequence of that set of sentences.

All of which means:

To show a set is inconsistent using resolution: simply start with the sentences, put into clauses, and derive the empty clause!

Or: if the set is already a bunch of clauses: simply derive the empty clause!  (and that on its turn shows that the original formula $F$ that the clauses came from is a contradiction (or, as a singleton set of sentences $\{ F \}$, is inconsistent ... which I assume is what they mean by $F$ being inconsistent)

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, to prove inconsistency we just resolve those clause and if we get an empty set then our original formula F, which we got our set from, is also inconsistent/unsatisfiable?

Comment: @name  Yes, that's all. You already have the clauses, so just derive the empty clause - which I know you can do! :) -  and you're done!

Comment: Also, if we do not get an empty clause then we prove that it is not inconsistent/satisfiable? To get the wording clear which is most confusing, inconsistent is another way to say unsatisfiable?

Comment: @name You want to be *really* careful with that: your inability to derive an empty clause may just be that: *your* inability to get an empty clause. That is, maybe the empty clause is derivable, but you just didn't find the right path to do so. In fact, for first-order logic, there are situations where you can derive more and more new clauses ... but you'll never get to an empty clause ... so how would you know that is impossible?  This is basically what's behind the fact that first-order logic is undecidable.  But yes: 'inconsistent' is the same as 'not satisfiable'.

Comment: So, in general, we can only prove that a formula is unsatisfiable in FOL not satisfiable?

Comment: @name Well, you can show *specific* sentence(s) to be satisfiable: if there are no more clauses left that you can resolve that will produce a new clause, and you haven't reached an empty clause, then you *can* say that the clause set is satisfiable.  To give a really simple example: starting with a single clause $[P]$, it is clear that nothing else can be resolved from that, certainly not the empty clause. So, that is satisfiable (indeed, simply set $P$ to true.  But there is no method that will be able to show that a set of sentences is satisfiable for *all* such sets.

Comment: Thats a perfect explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @name You're welcome! ... p.s. you should accept some of the answers you've gotten to your questions ...